# Substituir os simbolos < /> com Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria de saber como faço para substituir os símbolos `< />` com Javascript. Estou usando a tag `<code></code>` para exibir um código, porém não quero que ele seja renderizado no navegador. Sei que posso usar `&#60;` e `&#62;` para exibir uma <tag/> assim, mas gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de fazer o Javascript fazer isso por mim, procurar os símbolos e substituir automaticamente para que o código não seja renderizado.

Sei da existência de utilitários como o Syntax Highlighter, mas para esse caso só preciso exibir o código numa única página e não acho que seria interessante adicionar ele a página.

Comment: Já experimentou usar o DOM e os TextNode diretamente?

Comment: @luiscubal, desculpe não ter respondido antes, nem havia reparado seu comentário... Como eu faria isso que você disse?

Comment: `var textNode = document.createTextNode("Meu código"); codeNode.appendChild(textNode);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mexer no HTML dessa maneira é desaconselhado. 
Mas fôr de maneira controlada teste assim:

```
var conteudo= $('body').html(); // body ou o elemento que preferir
// apanhar comentários
conteudo = (conteudo.replace(/<!--/g, '&#60;&#33;&#45;&#45;')).replace(/-->/g, '&#45;&#45;&#62;');
// apanhar elementos
conteudo = (conteudo.replace(/</g, '&#60;')).replace(/>/g, '&#62;');
$('body').html('<pre>' + conteudo + '</pre>'); // juntei as tags <pre> para manter a formatação do código
```

Usei o [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) com uma [expressão regular](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular) que apanha o que está dentro das barras `/>/g`, e substitui pelo outro parâmetro. O `g` quer dizer multiplas vezes. Se não seria só a primeira ocorrência.

Este método é destrutivo se aplicado de novo à pagina uma vez que todas as tags, inclusve `<script>`, `<style>` são sobrepostas.

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/KR3AV/)

Estive a brincar mais um pouco com esta ideia, [**deixo aqui o exemplo**](http://jsbin.com/feveqafe).

Answer (score 2):

Dependendo dos seus requisitos, uma opção pode ser usar o tag `xmp` em vez de um Javascript. Ele está "deprecated", mas funciona na maioria dos browsers.

```
<xmp>
   <a href="blabla">bleble</a>
   <h1>Teste 123</h1>
</xmp>
```

Uma opção mais criativa é usar um `textarea` desativado e sem bordas:

```
<textarea disabled="true" style="border: none;background-color:white; width:500px; height: 300px;">
  <a href="blabla">bleble</a>
  <h1>Teste 123</h1>
</textarea>
```

Uma terceira opção (meio esquisita, hehe), seria usar um `<iframe>` referenciando um arquivo de texto com código.

Entretanto, recomendo que você tente mesmo trocar os caracteres (manualmente ou com a ajuda de alguma ferramenta), assim como você já indicou. Se for um código dinâmico, dá para fazer isso usando a linguagem da sua aplicação no servidor, e trazer o código já formatado para o browser. Por exemplo, em PHP (cuidado apenas com possíveis problemas de segurança, de preferência ignorar tags `<script>`):

```
htmlspecialchars('<h1>Teste 123</h1>')
```

E se for um código estático, é só usar o find/replace do seu editor. =D

Comment: A abordagem do xmp/textarea não funciona se o texto contiver `</xmp></textarea><script>alert('boom!');</script>`.

Comment: `<xmp><script>alert('boom!');</script></xmp>` funciona normalmente para mim (chrome).

Comment: Mas se tiver `<xmp>$texto</xmp>` e `$texto` for `</xmp><script>alert('boom');</script>`, então fica `<xmp></xmp><script>alert('boom');</script>`, que executa o script.

Comment: Ah sim, é verdade, vou adicionar um comentário.