# Imprimir código html

Tags: html, html5

Como imprimir código html ?

Exemplo:

```
<div id="css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.css.css"></div>
```

ele não imprime a tag link, ele linka outro css, quero escrever essa tag pro usuário ler...

Comment: Não é claro na sua pergunta se quer fazer isto do lado do cliente (javascript) ou servidor (php por exemplo).  Deixo um link relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11058/129

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para fazer isso você precisa escapar alguns caracteres especiais`**`, por exemplo:

```
" para &quot;   
' para &apos;   
& para &amp;    
< para &lt;
> para &gt;
```

Para facilitar você pode usar a função [`htmlentities`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

O código:

```
<div id="css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.css.css"></div>
```

Equivale:

```
&lt;div id=&quot;css&quot;&gt;&lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot;href=&quot;jquery.css.css&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
```

`**`Outros podem serem vistos [aqui](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_entities.htm).

Answer (score 5):

Use `&lt;` em vez de `<`, e `&gt;` em vez de `>`.

Answer (score 1):

Tu pode imprimir caracteres especiais em HTML usando [HTML Entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp).

Se quiser você pode usar este este conversor [aqui](http://htmlentities.net/).

Linguagens de servidor - como PHP, Ruby, Python - tem funções próprias para converter uma string em outra com caracteres codificados.

---

Quando você vai vai imprimir um texto qualquer que foi entrado pelo usuário (como um post de um blog, por exemplo) é recomendado utilizar esta função para evitar ataques de **Javascript injection**. Neste tipo de ataque alguém mal intencionado pode escrever tags `script` que rodarão na máquina do usuário sem o seu consentimento.