# Problema com echo em caracteres '<' '>' php

Tags: php, json

Ola, estou com o seguinte probleminha, estou utilizando uma api que me retorna um array json, porem em alguns desses dados vem entre < >, ex: < testenome > (nem aqui funcionou...tive que da um espaço kk), e nesses casos quando faço um echo fica em branco, entao fiz um teste fazendo um replace do '<' antes do echo...e foi exibido, nesse caso...como posso proceder contornar isso...pois eu precisaria que o dado fosse impresso do modo real?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11055/129

Comment: Obrigado Sergio funcionou perfeito.