# Substituir HTML entities dentro de uma Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um código `html` e preciso substituir parte dele por outro `html`, este código se encontra dentro de uma `div`.

Código:

```
<div id="aba-per" class="et_pb_module et_pb_tabs tab-per et_pb_tabs_0">
    <ul class="et_pb_tabs_controls clearfix">
        <li class="et_pb_tab_0 et_pb_tab_active"><a href="#">Teste &rarr; Teste</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Quero substituir `&rarr;` por `<br>`, ou seja, ao invés de mostrar a seta eu preciso que a linha seja quebrada.

Comment: Isso aparece só nesse sítio ou em mais sitios? Esse HTML é gerado no servidor? não dá para mudar lá?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como imprimir o conteúdo dentro de uma div HTML?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/782/como-imprimir-o-conte%c3%bado-dentro-de-uma-div-html)

Comment: @Sergio ao seu ver minha resposta é duplicada? :P Se for transformo em wiki e voto para fechar :)

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio acho que a pergunta não está clara o suficiente. Estou à espera também de clarificações.

Comment: Faltou um por que, qual a necessidade, de fato... mas achei que dava pra responder de acordo com o que foi perguntado, se bem que faria mais sentido esperar, visto que `&rarr;` só faz sentido do lado do servidor, a partir do momento que o browser renderiza não tem porque usar no javascript

Comment: Eu preciso que isto seja feito devido a um sistema que já está pronto em PHP, eu preciso modificar uma aba (tab) dentro dele, no painel de controle tem a opção de modificar, porém aceita somente 1 linha, eu quero colocar o título em 2 linhas.

Answer (score 1):

Acontece que `&rarr;` no navegador sera renderizado com seu caractere correspondente, no caso →

O que pode fazer é pegar o conteúdo usando `innerHTML`, fazer a alteração usando `replace` e atribuir o novo texto ao elemento div

```js
function teste() {
  var texto = document.getElementById("aba-per").innerHTML;
  texto = texto.replace("→", "<br/>");
  document.getElementById("aba-per").innerHTML = texto;
}
```

```html
<div id="aba-per" class="et_pb_module et_pb_tabs tab-per et_pb_tabs_0">
  <ul class="et_pb_tabs_controls clearfix">
    <li class="et_pb_tab_0 et_pb_tab_active"><a href="#">Teste &rarr; Teste</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button onclick="teste()">teste</button>
```

De qualquer modo me parece meio duplicada dessa pergunta aqui: [Substituir os simbolos < /> com Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11055/14262) veja a resposta do @Sergio